# Javascript regex positive negative decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that would match a positive and negative decimal value, empty string ('') and also minus only ('-'). Since I need it inside the function that handles the change of a numeric field and in order to add a negative value the user firstly adds the "-" or deletes the old value (""), I need to match all these 3 conditions.

So, to sum up, the regex should allow:

- positive & negative decimal values (also 0)
- "" (empty string)
- "-" (minus string)

What I have until now is:

```
function sanitizeInputValue(value: string) {
  var re = new RegExp('^$|^-?\\d{1,9}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$');
  return value.match(re) === null ? 0 : value;
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression? Why not `return value === "-" || value === "" || !isNaN(value) ? value : 0`

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? it seems your code works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can make matching the digits with decimal parts optional so you would also match the hyphen only `^$|^-?(?:\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?)?$`

As then all parts are optional, you can omit the `^$` and then all parts are optional.

```
^-?(?:\d{1,9}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{1,9}` match 1-9 times a digit
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match a dot and 1-2 digits
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional as well
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m7qtX2/1)

```js
var re = new RegExp("^-?(?:\\d{1,9}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)?$");

[
  "",
  "-",
  "1",
  "1.2",
  "test",
  "1234567890",
  "1.123",
  "-2",
  "-2.6"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + re.test(s)));
```

**Edit**

As you also want to match `-8.` and don't want to limit the amount of digits, you could use:

```
^-?(?:\d+\.?\d*)?$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional `-`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+\.?\d*` Match 1+ digits, optional dot and 0+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOacmb/1)

```js
var re = new RegExp("^-?(?:\\d+\\.?\\d*)?$");
[
  "-8.",
  "",
  "-",
  "1",
  "1.2",
  "test",
  "1234567890",
  "1.123",
  "-2",
  "-2.6"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s + " --> " + re.test(s))
);
```

Comment: I see that your solution doesn't match decimal values (-2, -2.6 ....)

Comment: @CristinaMarin: It does match those values. What makes you think it doesn't? Have you tested it?

Comment: ('-2.5').match(new RegExp('^-?(?:\d{1,9}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?$')) 

 returns null

Comment: @CristinaMarin You have to double escape the backslash in the RegExp constructor. I have added an example in Javascript.

Comment: @CristinaMarin: Or use a regex literal: `/^-?(?:\d{1,9}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?$/.test("-2.6")`.

Comment: @CristinaMarin I have added an update to account for `"-8."` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript's built in `Number` to convert the string into a numeric value right before you return from the function.

Also, I modified your regex so that it can accept input like `.23` and `0.2345`.

```js
function sanitizeInputValue(value) {
  var re = new RegExp('^$|^-?(\\d+)?(\\.?\\d*)?$');
  return value.match(re) === null ? 0 : Number(value);
}

console.log(sanitizeInputValue("-23"));     // -23
console.log(sanitizeInputValue("42.123"));  //  42.123
console.log(sanitizeInputValue("-.34"));    // -0.34
console.log(sanitizeInputValue(""));        //  0
console.log(sanitizeInputValue("-8."));     //  -8
console.log(sanitizeInputValue("-8.4"));     // -8.4
```

Comment: `Number("-")` returns `NaN` though. It sounded like `"-"` was valid input but maybe I got that wrong.

Comment: Apparently I need it to match "-8." because the user is going to input a negative decimal value, help? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sanitizeInputValue(value) {
  var re = /^$|\-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d*)?|-/;
  return value.match(re) ? value : 0;
}
```